# how to trigger click event to li using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to trrigger click event on span tag onclick happed.
li created when create/click span tag( create collection) click.

below is my span nd ul li tag. li list added dynamically into the ul when click on the span.

**i want trigger click event on li only data-encat value will be 0**. Otherwise no need to trigger.

```
<span data-object_id="2089" class="cbxwpbkmark-field-create-submit" title="Create Collection"></span>

<ul class="cbxlbjs-list cbxwpbkmarklist" style="" data-type="product" data-object_id="670">
<li class="cbxlbjs-item" data-catname="2563" data-privacy="0" data-incat="1" data-value="64">
<span title="2563" class="cbxlbjs-item-name">2563</span>
</li>
<li class="cbxlbjs-item" data-catname="testt" data-privacy="0" data-incat="0" data-value="65">
<span title="testt" class="cbxlbjs-item-name">testt</span></li>
<li class="cbxlbjs-item" data-catname="gdgfd" data-privacy="0" data-incat="1" data-value="66">
<span title="gdgfd" class="cbxlbjs-item-name">gdgfd</span></li>
</ul>
```

Below is my jquery code i m trying but it apply all the data-cat values(li)

```
jQuery('.cbxwpbkmark-field-create-submit').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
                            var successmesg = $('.cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success').html();
                            if(successmesg == 'Done successfully!')
                            {
                                //var a = $("li.cbxlbjs-item").length;
                                //alert(a);
                                $('.cbxlbjs-item').trigger("click");
                                $('.cbxwpbkmark-toolbar-listcat').trigger("click");
                             }
                        }, 3000);
  });
```

ANyone have idea how to do this then let me know.

Comment: First where is the element with class `cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success'`, second you write `Below is my jquery code i m trying but it apply all the data-cat values(li)` but I cant see any code that tries that.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen I want apply trigger click event only data-cat value 0 li element. Search this class you get that class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
// grab all li's with data-incat attribute with value of zero
var liRefs = $("[data-incat='0']");

// trigger click
liRefs.trigger('click');
```

Comment: Its not working on first element . also need to refresh the page  after that checkbox will be selected

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
jQuery(document).find('[data-incat="0"]').trigger('click');
```

or

```
jQuery(document).find('[data-incat="0"]').click();
```

Not tested.